# Handlebars.js Loop Within a Loop

Tags: loops, handlebars.js

I have a master object filled with Budget information.  Each element within the Budget portion of the object has a Category with a Category Name and then 12 more fields.  These fields are called Jan, Feb, ..., Dec and have the values of the Budget item for the corresponding month.

In another section of the master object, I have an array of month names called monthList (Jan, Feb, ..., Dec).

What I would like to do is {{#each}} through the Budget items to create one `<tr>` per Budget Category.  But, rather than have my handlebars template have a separate `<td>` defined for each of the 12 months, I would like to iterate through the monthList and create one `<td>` per month across the table.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this happen.  I suspect it's with a handlebars helper, but I'm not quite seeing how to do it.

My data object looks like this:

```
var data = {
  budget: [{
    category: "Rent",
    Jan: "300",
    Feb: "300",
    Mar: "300",
    Apr: "300",
    May: "300",
    Jun: "300",
    Jul: "300",
    Aug: "300",
    Sep: "300",
    Oct: "300",
    Nov: "300",
    Dec: "300"
  }, {
    category: "Utilities",
    Jan: "100",
    Feb: "100",
    Mar: "100",
    Apr: "100",
    May: "100",
    Jun: "100",
    Jul: "100",
    Aug: "100",
    Sep: "100",
    Oct: "100",
    Nov: "100",
    Dec: "100"
  }, {
    category: "Food",
    Jan: "400",
    Feb: "400",
    Mar: "400",
    Apr: "400",
    May: "400",
    Jun: "400",
    Jul: "400",
    Aug: "400",
    Sep: "400",
    Oct: "400",
    Nov: "400",
    Dec: "400"
  }, {
    category: "Beer",
    Jan: "1000",
    Feb: "1000",
    Mar: "1000",
    Apr: "1000",
    May: "1500",
    Jun: "1500",
    Jul: "1500",
    Aug: "1500",
    Sep: "1000",
    Oct: "1000",
    Nov: "1000",
    Dec: "1000"
  }, {
    category: "Golf",
    Jan: "3000",
    Feb: "3000",
    Mar: "3000",
    Apr: "3000",
    May: "5000",
    Jun: "5000",
    Jul: "5000",
    Aug: "5000",
    Sep: "5000",
    Oct: "3000",
    Nov: "3000",
    Dec: "3000"
  }],
  monthList: {
    1: "Jan",
    2: "Feb",
    3: "Mar",
    4: "Apr",
    5: "May",
    6: "Jun",
    7: "Jul",
    8: "Aug",
    9: "Sep",
    10: "Oct",
    11: "Nov",
    12: "Dec"
  }
};
```

I have a jsfiddle that sets things up and shows how to accomplish this by manually creating a `<td>`.  The `<thead>` section has `<th>` elements that were created the way I would like to create the `<td>` elements in the body of the `<table>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/gregorylmartin/1ynpk6rt/6/

My actual use case is more complex, of course.  But, this is a concept I will be able to re-use extensively in this application once I get the technique figured out.

Comment: The only real probelm you are facing is that you need to map your original data-structure to something better adapted to Handlebars.
Just transform your Budget objects into `{categoryName: value, expenses: []}`
Handling it with handlebars is not where that logic should be done, as you said it's inefficient. I'd add that's it's not your Views' concern, either. It shouldn't have to know that much about your data.

Comment: Sebastian is 100% correct.  I tiny JS loop and my data is transformed into a format more suitable for Handlebars.  Here is the revised fiddle...    
[https://jsfiddle.net/gregorylmartin/1ynpk6rt/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/gregorylmartin/1ynpk6rt/7/)

Comment: Added a little Helper for even more functionality.  Pretty powerful stuff... [https://jsfiddle.net/gregorylmartin/1ynpk6rt/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/gregorylmartin/1ynpk6rt/8/)

Comment: did you find a way or want me to write a solution @user3245690?

Answer (score 0):

The answer below even it's been a year since asked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = {
    categories: [{
        "name": "Rent",
        "budget": {
          "Jan": "300",
          "Feb": "300",
          "Mar": "300",
          "Apr": "300",
          "May": "300",
          "Jun": "300",
          "Jul": "300",
          "Aug": "300",
          "Sep": "300",
          "Oct": "300",
          "Nov": "300",
          "Dec": "300"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Utilities",
        "budget": {
          "Jan": "100",
          "Feb": "100",
          "Mar": "100",
          "Apr": "100",
          "May": "100",
          "Jun": "100",
          "Jul": "100",
          "Aug": "100",
          "Sep": "100",
          "Oct": "100",
          "Nov": "100",
          "Dec": "100"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Food",
        "budget": {
          "Jan": "400",
          "Feb": "400",
          "Mar": "400",
          "Apr": "400",
          "May": "400",
          "Jun": "400",
          "Jul": "400",
          "Aug": "400",
          "Sep": "400",
          "Oct": "400",
          "Nov": "400",
          "Dec": "400"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Beer",
        "budget": {
          "Jan": "1000",
          "Feb": "1000",
          "Mar": "1000",
          "Apr": "1000",
          "May": "1500",
          "Jun": "1500",
          "Jul": "1500",
          "Aug": "1500",
          "Sep": "1000",
          "Oct": "1000",
          "Nov": "1000",
          "Dec": "1000"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Golf",
        "budget": {
          "Jan": "3000",
          "Feb": "3000",
          "Mar": "3000",
          "Apr": "3000",
          "May": "5000",
          "Jun": "5000",
          "Jul": "5000",
          "Aug": "5000",
          "Sep": "5000",
          "Oct": "3000",
          "Nov": "3000",
          "Dec": "3000"
        }
      }
    ],
    months: {
      0: "Category",
      1: "Jan",
      2: "Feb",
      3: "Mar",
      4: "Apr",
      5: "May",
      6: "Jun",
      7: "Jul",
      8: "Aug",
      9: "Sep",
      10: "Oct",
      11: "Nov",
      12: "Dec"
    }
  };

  var tdData = document.getElementById("td-template").innerHTML;
  var thData = document.getElementById("th-template").innerHTML;

  var tdTemplate = Handlebars.compile(tdData);
  var thTemplate = Handlebars.compile(thData);

  var result1 = tdTemplate(data);
  var result2 = thTemplate(data);

  document.getElementById('tdBudget').innerHTML += result1;
  document.getElementById('thBudget').innerHTML += result2;

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}

table {
  margin: 10px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

th {
  background: #ccc;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

td a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.numbers {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="th-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each months}}
  <th class='centered'>{{this}}</th>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="td-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each categories}}
  <tr>
    <td class='numbers'>{{this.name}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Jan}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Feb}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Mar}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Apr}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.May}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Jun}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Jul}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Aug}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Sep}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Oct}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Nov}}</td>
    <td class="numbers">{{this.budget.Dec}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr id="thBudget">
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="centered" id="tdBudget">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```